# Cena de los filosofos VB6

Tags: vb, vb6

aqui molestando de nuevo, se que el lenguaje y el IDE es viejo, pero podrian ayudarme a terminar el programa? para los filosofos intente hacer un array de textbox, pero me salen los siguientes errores, el programa es un clasico de la programacion sincronizada pero no logro terminarlo

anexo descripciones de los errores y lo que se intenta hacer con el codigo

a la hora de ejecutarlo aparecen los errores descritos mas abajo y donde

se intenta hacer con arreglo de textbox

agradeceria mucho su apoyo para encontrar una solucion a este programa, saludos :)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Error[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

codigo

```
Dim N As Integer 'NÚMERO DE FILOSOFOS

Dim HAMBRIENTOS(1 To 3), tlibre(0 To 4) As Integer 'hambrientos es una array 
unidimensional(pila) que contiene a los filósofos que están hambrientos

Dim Filosofos(5) As TextBox

Dim tenedor As Line

Dim k, L, I, CONT, INICIAL, FINAL As Integer ' LAS CUATRO PRIMERAS VARIABLES SON PARA 
AVANZAR EN LOS BUCLES Y LAS 2

Private Sub CMDcomer_Click()

'ASIGNO LA POSICION EN LA MESA A CADA FILOSOFO(PROCESO) INICIALMENTE TODOS LOS TENEDORES(RECURSOS) ESTAN LIBRES

For N = 0 To 4

Filosofos(N) = N

tlibre(N) = True

Next N



'INICIALMENTE TODOS ESTAN PENSANDO

For N = 0 To 4

Filosofos(N) = "PEN"

Filosofos(N).BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 0)

Next N



'ASIGANMOS UN VALOR INICIAL ALEATORIO PARA DETERMINAR AL PRIMER HAMBRIENTO

INICIAL = Int((5 * Rnd) + 1) 'GENERA UN VALOR ALEATORIO ENTRE 1 Y 5

Select Case INICIAL

Case 1

FINAL = 5

Case 2

FINAL = 6

Case 3

FINAL = 7

Case 4

FINAL = 8

Case 5

FINAL = 9

End Select

J = 0

'ASIGNAMOS EL ESTADO HAMBRIENTO DEJANDO UNO Y CAMBIANDO DE COLOR A ROJO

k = 0

CONT = 0

For N = INICIAL To FINAL Step 2

 J = N

If N > 5 Then

If N = 6 Or N = 8 Then J = CONT + 1

If N = 7 Or N = 9 Then J = CONT + 2

CONT = CONT + 2

End If

Filosofos(J) = "HAM"

k = k + 1

HAMBRIENTOS(k) = J

Filosofos(J).BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)

Next N

Timer1.Enabled = True

End Sub



Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
'PASA DEL ESTADO HAMBRIENTO A COMIENDO EVALUANDO SI LOS TENEDORES DE LA IZQUIERDA Y   DERECHA ESTAN DISPONIBLES Y SI ES ASI CAMBIARÁN AL COLOR VERDE.

For k = 1 To 3

If HAMBRIENTOS(k) = 1 Then

If tlibre(HAMBRIENTOS(k) + 4) = True And tlibre(HAMBRIENTOS(k)) = True Then

tlibre(HAMBRIENTOS(k) + 4) = False

tlibre(HAMBRIENTOS(k)) = False

tenedor(HAMBRIENTOS(k) + 4).Visible = False

tenedor(HAMBRIENTOS(k)).Visible = False

Filosofos(HAMBRIENTOS(k)) = "COM"

Filosofos(HAMBRIENTOS(k)).BackColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)

End If

End If

If HAMBRIENTOS(k) <> 1 Then

If tlibre(HAMBRIENTOS(k) - 1) = True And tlibre(HAMBRIENTOS(k)) = True Then

tlibre(HAMBRIENTOS(k) - 1) = False

tlibre(HAMBRIENTOS(k)) = False

tenedor(HAMBRIENTOS(k) - 1).Visible = False

tenedor(HAMBRIENTOS(k)).Visible = False

Filosofos(HAMBRIENTOS(k)) = "COM"

FIL1(HAMBRIENTOS(k)).BackColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)

End If

End If

Next k

Timer1.Enabled = False

Timer2.Enabled = True

End Sub

Private Sub Timer2_Timer()
'EN LA SEGUNDA PASADA EVALUAN LOS ESTADOS DE LOS FILOSOFOS Y DEJAN TENEDOR

L = 0

For N = 1 To 5

If Filosofos(N) = "HAM" Then

L = L + 1

HAMBRIENTOS(L) = N

Else

If Filosofos(N) = "PEN" Then

L = L + 1

HAMBRIENTOS(L) = N

FIL1(N).BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)

Else

If Filosofos(N) = "COM" Then

Filosofos(N) = "PEN"

If N = 1 Then

tlibre(N) = True

tlibre(N + 4) = True 'DEJAMOS LIBRE TENEDOR DERECHO

tenedor(N).Visible = True

tenedor(N + 4).Visible = True

Else 'E IZQUIERDO RESPECTIVAMENTE

If N <> 1 Then

tlibre(N) = True

tlibre(N - 1) = True

tenedor(N).Visible = True

tenedor(N - 1).Visible = True

End If

End If

FIL1(N).BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 0)

End If

End If

End If

Next N

Timer2.Enabled = False

Timer1.Enabled = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Quizás si colocas todo el proyecto en un drive y compartes por aquí el enlace, sería más fácil ayudarte, dado que lo otro es reproducir todo lo que envías y eso es un tiempo que no necesariamente tiene la gente.

Comment: Hace mil años que no veo vb6, pero creo que tu error es que estas asignando N a un textbox, no a la propiedad text, deberías poner algo así Filosofos(N).text= N. Lo que no recuerdo es que si es posible agregar un entero, si no fuera posible tienes que convertir a string Filosofos(N).text= CStr(N). Lo otro es que ocupas la variable N como global y también la ocupas dentro de una subrrutina, no debes volver a ocupar los mismos nombres de las variables globales

Comment: Como duda personal, porque elegiste usar VB6, habiendo lenguajes mucho más modernos???

Comment: en VB.net no puedo levantarlo del todo :/

Comment: Como es que no puedes levantarlo? A mi VB6 me encantaba, pero no sé si será productivo aprenderlo hoy, es como aprender latín. Por otro lado, te sirvió mi primer comentario?